# i got this error in laravel hosted code not in localhost when composer install given

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

> Deprecation Notice: Required parameter $path follows optional parameter $schema in /usr/share/php/JsonSchema/Constraints/UndefinedConstraint.php:62

> Deprecation Notice: Required parameter $path follows optional parameter $schema in /usr/share/php/JsonSchema/Constraints/UndefinedConstraint.php:108

> Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130

> Deprecation Notice: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /usr/share/php/Composer/Repository/RepositoryManager.php:130

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.

>PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: array_merge() does not accept unknown named parameters in /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/DefaultPolicy.php:84
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: array_merge()
#1 /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/DefaultPolicy.php(84): call_user_func_array()
#2 /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php(387): Composer\DependencyResolver\DefaultPolicy->selectPreferredPackages()
#3 /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php(740): Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->selectAndInstall()
#4 /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php(231): Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->runSat()
#5 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(489): Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->solve()
#6 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer.php(232): Composer\Installer->doInstall()
#7 /usr/share/php/Composer/Command/InstallCommand.php(122): Composer\Installer->run()
#8 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(255): Composer\Command\InstallCommand->execute()
#9 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(934): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#10 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#11 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(281): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#12 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(149): Composer\Console\Application->doRun()
#13 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(113): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#14 /usr/bin/composer(62): Composer\Console\Application->run()
#15 {main}
```

what is the issue here whether my php version in host cousing the problem, how to solve

Comment: Did you follow the recomendations

Comment: I have solved the issue by deleting vendor folder and re-installing composer